# Passing to SOAP arguments from the command line

Tags: python, xml, soap

I have a python script that successfully sends SOAP to insert a record into a system.  The values are static in the test.  I need to make the value dynamic/argument that is passed through the command line or other stored value.

execute: python myscript.py

`<d4p1:Address>MainStreet</d4p1:Address>` ....this works to add hard coded "MainStreet"

execute:  python myscript.py MainStreet

...this is now trying to pass the argument MainStreet

`<d4p1:Address>sys.argv[1]</d4p1:Address>`  ....this does not work

It saves the literal text address as "sys.argv[1]" ... I have imported sys ..I have tried %, {}, etc from web searches, what syntax am I missing??

Answer (score 0):

You need to read a little about how to create strings in Python, below is how it could look like in your code. Sorry it's hard to say more without seeing your actual code. And you actually shouldn't create XMLs like that, you should use for instance xml module from standard library.

```
test = "<d4p1:Address>" + sys.argv[1] + "</d4p1:Address>"
```